# How to replace escape character with a string

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to  replace escape character with a string but the query is giving me an irrelevant result

eg- char- '\'  replace with 'adfc' with below query

```
SELECT REPLACE("abcdefgh\i","\\", "adfc" );
```

**output** - abcdefghi

**Desired output** - abcdefghadfci

How can i achieve this in mysql?

Comment: The way I see it, if '\\' represents '\' "escaped" then on the first string the '\i' will just represent 'i' "escaped". Maybe try to double '\\' the first string too

Comment: @sagi I want to achieve something like "REPLACE("abcdefgh\i","\", "adfc" );" but "\" doesn't work as \ escapes the inverted commas and query error comes.

Comment: @Rakim We are getting the first string from data itself. So we can't change it but wanted to manipulate it later on.

Comment: did you try to input the first string as an actual variable then instead of testing with strings?

Comment: like the actual query you are going to use instead of testing with strings `SELECT REPLACE(var,"\\", "adfc" );`

Comment: Your input string doesn't contain any escape character, it contains an escaped character. There is a difference.

Comment: Try that please `SELECT REPLACE("abcdefgh\i","\", "adfc" );`

Comment: @Rakim wrong , same result i have got

Comment: @Rakim that will give error check [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432995/how-to-replace-escape-character-with-a-string#comment58564159_35432995)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. `\i` is a single character to the SQL engine, thus there is no separate escape character to replace.

Comment: Then you either need to escape the '\' to '\\' in the first string OR change the delimiter to '\i' instead of '\\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your my.ini add this line:

```
sql-mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES"
```

then restart your mysql server, and replace your query with this:

```
SELECT REPLACE("abcdefgh\i","\", "adfc" );
```

reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT REPLACE("abcdefgh\\i","\\", "adfc" );
```

single escape character will automatically escape character, so you need to put double escape character for remove escape character.